# Python template forloop doesn't work more than one time

Tags: python, templates, for-loop, flask

I am new to Python, I am using flask. I am trying to fetch the data from database, which I successfully get. The data is going to be used in multiple place like in different dropdown selects and values in option would be dynamic from database in same index template.

But when I run for loop only in template, only the first loop works other doesn't work at all. I have also check the data from database is retrieving. By first loop I mean lets suppose I iterate loop in select dropdown list like this:

Python code:

```
def configure_routes(app):
@app.route('/')  # URL '/' to be handled by main() route handler
def main(name=None):
ret = class.get_data()
return render_template('index.html', name=name, data=ret)
```

HTML markup:

```
<select id="targ_xyz" class="form-control">
<option>Select Target xyz</option>
<option>
{% for rows in data %}
{{rows}}
{% endfor %}
</option>
```

Now this code works, just next to it there is next select dropdown with the same loop and and the results from same data variable has to be extracted.

```
<select id="targ_tech" class="form-control">
<option>Select Target tech</option>
<option>
{% for row2 in data %}
{{row2.tech}}
{% endfor %}
</option>

This is my template where i want to add the python code in select options
<div id = "tech_sep">
<select id="sel_sep_tech" class="form-control">
<option>Select Target Technology</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id = "abc_ch">
<select id = "abc_ch_sel" class="form-control">
<option>Choose Expertise</option>
</select>   
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<div id = "targ_sep">
<select id="xyz_ch" class="form-control">
<option>Select Target</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This code or below this any loop doesn't work at all. I would appreciate if someone can help, or someone can guide me how many loops we can use in one html template with Python also how to use them in proper way.

THanks.

Comment: Are you sure there is something in ```.tech``` in each ```row2``? Can you print the data ?

Comment: yes i am able to print the data and when i run any of them first that works but not the second loop.

Comment: In second loop you are printing ```row2.tech```. Confirm that each ```row2``` has some attribute called ```tech```

Comment: can you check am i using the right way to run for loop and how many loops we can use in one template and how?

Comment: Yes row 2 is the name which we use to refer in loop , LIke: for row2 in data

Comment: data is coming from same data variable. in both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in the past. you could test the following, as you stated that the for loop is based on the same variable?

```
{% for rows in data %}
  <select id="targ_xyz" class="form-control">
  <option>Select Target xyz</option>
  <option>
    {{rows}}
  </option>

  <select id="targ_tech" class="form-control">
  <option>Select Target tech</option>
  <option>
    {{rows.tech}}
  </option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I already tried this i repeats the option of select target tech on each iteration and it shows many time. I have also tries many other ways such as keeping them together or trying to extract the data and make variable on top of the file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Brainfart: return render_template('index.html', name=name, data=ret, datatech = ret). And then in your template change the second for loop variable to datatech. If this is something you also tried, please be more complete in your initial information. Also it would be a good idea to post your template, i can only suspect something is wrong there.

Comment: I tested the following. hope this helps. I used a list as data source. You might want to check if yours. `def main(): test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] return render_template('test.html', data = test)`. Template is as follows: `<div id="tech_sep">  <select class="form-control" id="sel_sep_tech">  <option> Select Target Technology </option> {% for row in data %} <option> {{row}} </option> {% endfor %} </select> </div> <div id="abc_ch"> <select class="form-control" id="abc_ch_sel"> <option> Choose Expertise </option> {% for row in data %} <option> {{row}} </option> {% endfor %} </select> </div>`